# Apache Camel trims off apostrophes from String message body

Tags: string, apache-camel, javabeans, message-body

```java
import static java.lang.System.out;

import org.apache.camel.ExchangePattern;
import org.apache.camel.Message;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

class RequestReplyMessageSample {

    class Replier {

        String reply( final String /*Message*/ /*Exchange*/ request ) {
            out.println( "\n[ERROR] Expected: 'Re'quest', Actual: " + request
                    + "  <-- Am I doing somethig wrong, is this a bug or a feature?\n" );
            return String.format( "**** Replying to %s ****%n", request/*.getMessage()*/ /*.getBody( String.class )*/ );
        }
    } // Replier

    private static final DefaultCamelContext cc = new DefaultCamelContext();

    public static void main( final String... args ) throws Exception {

        final Replier replier = new RequestReplyMessageSample().new Replier();

        cc.setName( "Request Reply Sample" );
        cc.addRoutes( new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() {

                from( "timer:start?repeatCount=1" )
                        .setExchangePattern( ExchangePattern.InOut )
                        .process().message( m -> m.setBody( "'Re'quest'" ) ) // EIP Request
                        .process().message( m -> print( "Request", m ) )
                        .log( "Requesting..." )
                        .log( "Replying..." )
                        // How to get Message (or Exchange) as argument in here?
                        .bean( replier, "reply(${body})" ) // EIP Requestor/Replier
                        .process().message( m -> print( "Reply", m ) ) // EIP Reply (in the body of the Message)
                        .setId( "Request/Reply" );
            }
        } );
        cc.start();
        Thread.sleep( 2000 );
        cc.stop();
        cc.close();
    } // main()

    static void print( final String endpoint, final Message m ) {

        out.printf( "%s %s: %s%n", endpoint, m, m.getBody() );
    } // print()

} // RequestReplyMessageSample
```

#### Output

```
...
Request Message: 'Re'quest'
[ple) thread #1 - timer://start] Request/Reply                  INFO  Requesting...
[ple) thread #1 - timer://start] Request/Reply                  INFO  Replying...

[ERROR] Expected: 'Re'quest', Actual: Re'quest  <-- Am I doing somethig wrong, is this a bug or a feature?

Reply Message: **** Replying to Re'quest ****
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [feature](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html#_operator_support). In this case, the single quotes at the start/end of the expression are interpreted as a [string literal start/end](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-3.7.0/core/camel-core-languages/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/language/simple/SimplePredicateParser.java#L577). You need to add another single quote to let the parser see it as character (i.e. `m.setBody("''Re'quest''")`).

Comment: I believe you that this is a feature. However, neither the doc chapter nor the code you link says anything about apostrophe trimming (explicitely). Re the first: I'm not using any operator. I'm just setting a header with a string. Re the second: The `boolean singleQuotedLiteralText()` just checks and returns whether a text is single quoted.

Comment: It is not trimmed, it is simply interpreted as string literal start/end char, rather than apostrophe char.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the body is passed as explicit method parameter to the bean.

The **single quotes are preserved** in the following scenarios:

- pass the string as message body in the request
- set (or overwrite) the body in the route (`.setBody`) as constant
- set (or overwrite) the body in the route (`.setBody`) as expression
- [passing the body implicit to a bean](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/bean-binding.html#BeanBinding-Parameterbinding)
- set (or overwrite) the body through a bean method return value
- set (or overwrite) the body through a processor bean

Only when the body is **[passed explicitly to a bean method](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/bean-binding.html#BeanBinding-Parameterbindingusingmethodoption)**, the quotes are interpreted as string literal boundaries.

```
.bean(new EchoBean(), "echoBody(${body})")
```

becomes in your case

```
.bean(new EchoBean(), "echoBody('Re'quest')")
```

You can try this test class (Camel 3, JUnit 5). It fails because the quotes are lost in the last bean call with explicit parameters.

```
package test.camel;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit5.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class QuoteTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    public static final String MOCK_OUTPUT = "mock:output";

    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from( "direct:start" )
                        .log("Reveived body: ${body}")
                        .setBody(constant("'Re'quest'"))
                        .log("Body overwritten in route: ${body}")
                        .bean(new EchoBean())
                        .log("Body overwritten through bean: ${body}")
                        .process().message( m -> m.setBody( "'Re'quest'" ) )
                        .log("Body overwritten through processor: ${body}")
                        .bean(new EchoBean(), "echoBody(${body})")
                        .log("Body overwritten through bean with methodparameter: ${body}")
                        .to(MOCK_OUTPUT);
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    void routeTest_quoteHandling_processed() throws Exception {
        getMockEndpoint(MOCK_OUTPUT).expectedBodiesReceived("'Re'quest'");
        template.requestBody("direct:start", "'Re'quest'");
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }

    static class EchoBean {
        public String echoBody(final String messageBody) {
            System.out.println("Expected: 'Re'quest', Actual: " + messageBody);
            return messageBody;
        }
    }
}
```

It produces the following output. As you can see, the quotes are preserved through all steps except the last bean call with explicit parameter passing

```
09:00:53.521 [main] INFO  route1 - Reveived body: 'Re'quest'
09:00:53.521 [main] INFO  route1 - Body overwritten in route: 'Re'quest'
Expected: 'Re'quest', Actual: 'Re'quest'
09:00:53.527 [main] INFO  route1 - Body overwritten through bean: 'Re'quest'
09:00:53.527 [main] INFO  route1 - Body overwritten through processor: 'Re'quest'
Expected: 'Re'quest', Actual: Re'quest  <<-- only when the body is passed as method parameter, the quotes are lost
09:00:53.529 [main] INFO  route1 - Body overwritten through bean with methodparameter: Re'quest
```